# checkstyle getSQLTypeName

Tags: java, maven, warnings, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I'm using the Checkstyle Maven Plugin for my project and having a problem with `getSQLTypeName`.
This method is described in an interface `SQLData`.
In my code I implemented this method. For example:

```
@Override
public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
    return ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME;
}
```

When I run Checkstyle, I have a warning:

```
Unexpected getter name
```

What can you advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is generated by [Sevntu Checkstyle](http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.com/sevntu.checkstyle/)'s *SimpleAccessorNameNotationCheck*. Seventu Checkstyle is a third-party add-on to Checkstyle. This check ensures that getter names correspond to the names of the fields they return.

So, your getter `getSQLTypeName()` should return the contents of a field called `sqlTypeName`. In your case, it's a constant called `ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME`, which doesn't match.

The detailed documentation of this check is [here](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/blob/master/sevntu-checks/src/main/java/com/github/sevntu/checkstyle/checks/coding/SimpleAccessorNameNotationCheck.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot!   
I really use Sevntu Checkstyle plugin and forgot to write this.  
I renamed `ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME` to `SQLTYPENAME` and validation finished correct.
How did you know that is SimpleAccessorNameNotationCheck.java ?

Comment: *How did you know that is SimpleAccessorNameNotationCheck.java?* - I was pretty sure that it wasn't standard Checkstyle, so I googled the error message and then looked through the sevntu sources on github.